# Forming the maximum number out of the available numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following question https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/largest-number/ : Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

For example:

Given [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], the largest formed number is 9534330.

Note: The result may be very large, so you need to return a string instead of an integer.

I have been able to solve it and implemented it, using comparison based sorting technique. That is, given two numbers X and Y, I compare two numbers XY (Y appended at the end of X) and YX (X appended at the end of Y). If XY is larger, then X should come before Y in output, else Y should come before. The following is the code:

```
string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
    // Do not write main() function.
    // Do not read input, instead use the arguments to the function.
    // Do not print the output, instead return values as specified
    // Still have a doubt. Checkout www.interviewbit.com/pages/sample_codes/ for more details
    vector<string> myvec;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        string s = to_string(A[i]);
        myvec.push_back(s);
    }
    sort(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),mycomp());
    string s = "";
    auto it = myvec.begin();
    while (it != myvec.end())
    {
        string p = *it;
        s = s + p;
        it++;
    }
    return s;
}

struct mycomp
{
    inline bool operator() (const string &p1, const string &p2)
    {
        string s1 = p1.append(p2);
        string s2 = p2.append(p1);
        if (s1.compare(s2) < 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
};
```

But, the problem is, I have to merge the two functions into a single one because I just have to implement the single function. I cannot define one more function since I have no control over the entire piece of code (look at the link's submission part). Therefore, my ask is, how can I use the comparator by defining it inside the function `string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &A)`. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can have multiple methods in interview bit. Its not necessary to write everything in one method.

Comment: Use a lambda! Instead of `sort(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),mycomp());` write `sort(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),[](const string &p1, const string &p2) -> bool { /* the operator()s content */ });`

Comment: `while (it != myvec.end()) {  string p = *it; s = s + p; it++;  }` -- That can be rewritten as `string p = std::accumulate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), std::string());`.  No need for temporary strings or temporary iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect place for a lambda.

```
sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), [](const string &p1, const string &p2) {
  string s1(p1 + p2);
  string s2(p2 + p1);
  return s1.compare(s2) >= 0;
});
```

I changed your code to not call append() on the strings, since you accept them as references to const objects, and p1.append(p2) tries to modify p1, but that's not allowed on a const object.  Further, avoid constructs like if(x) return true else return false;  and instead just return x;

Also, this

```
string s = "";
auto it = myvec.begin();
while (it != myvec.end())
{
    string p = *it;
    s = s + p;
    it++;
}
return s;
```

Can be condensed to:

```
string s;
for (auto const& e : myvec)
    s += e;
return s;
```

(Assuming you have a c++11 compiler or later)

Comment: excellent solution. but i think there's a ')' missing at the end of the lambda expression